# invalid date syntax with ajax calendar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I had Ajax calendar and when I selected from it it give me date as (07/12/2010)

and when I made space between the year and / it converted to (2010/07/12) and this invalid date so pleas what the error.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, especially what you mean by `made space between the year and /`? Posting some of your code would also help a lot.

Comment: Hoora ! iioiooioo will move away from SO all mispelled 'calendar' word !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a error is it? It sounds to me like the Ajax is just setting the date as a culture invariant. See [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cultureinvariantdatetime.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try Specifying the date Format by using calendar Format property to "dd/MM/yyyy"

http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/aspnet_ajax_calendarextender_and_validation.php

Check out http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from JS you would be better off working from its numeric (epoch) representation and then convert it to whatever format you want to use or use the js date api to achieve what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date